# <li> titles and descriptions align across top

Tags: css, list, alignment

Not quite sure how to go about describing what it is I'm trying to achieve, so I have some screenshots.. Basically, I'd like the `<h2>`s all have their top edges align, as well as the `<p>`'s.

What I currently have:
[image: current]

What I would like to have:
[image: ideal]

index.html

```
<div id="services">
    <p><span>Services</span></p>
    <ul>
    <li><h2>Identity and Logo Design</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    <li><h2>Branding</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    <li><h2>Web Design and Development</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    <li><h2>Social Media</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="next">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/next.png" alt="Click for more information" /></a>
    </div><!-- end next -->
</div><!-- end services -->
```

style.css

```
#services {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#services p span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#services ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 160px;
}

#services ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
} 

#services ul li h2 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#services .next {
    float: right
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about giving the `<h2>`s a height, eg

```
#services ul li h2 {
    height:2.5em;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/trc6G/)

Edit

If you don't have a height the element size will depend on its content, some of you headers have more text than others forcing the text to wrap, which will have a different height than the one liners.

Your paragraphs vertical position will depend on the height of the headers so if all the headers have the same height, then paragraphs will have the same vertical position.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.
I'm curious to know why that works, though, if you wouldn't mind explaining? I never would have thought to establish a height..